# What needs to change in this package.json file to work with npm 0.3.0?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, package, npm

Trying to use a lib but getting this error...

```
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Note that package.json must be actual JSON, not
npm ERR! JSON.parse just a JavaScript object.
npm ERR! JSON.parse 
npm ERR! JSON.parse This changed in npm 0.3.0, and is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! JSON.parse Tell the package author to fix their package.json file.
```

Not sure what changes are likely needed to make it valid JSON, thanks very much!

Comment: @fancy check my answer, I think its the most elegant way. Can you reset the anser ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Valid JSON must have both keys and values of an object in quotes. Surround all of your keys in quotation marks and that should make the error go away.

Reference: [JSON spec](http://json.org/)

**Update**: I did the dirty work for you. Let me know if this fixes it.

```
{ "name": "embedly"
, "version": "0.3.2"
, "description": "Embedly client library for node"
, "homepage": "https://github.com/embedly/embedly-node"
, "keywords": []
, "author":
  { "name": "Bob Corsaro"
  , "email": "bob@embed.ly"
  , "url": "http://www.google.com/profiles/rcorsaro"
  }
, "repository":
  { "type": "git"
  , "url": "git://github.com/embedly/embedly-node"
  }
, "bugs": { "web": "http://github.com/embedly/embedly-node/issues/" }
, "directories":
  { "doc": "./docs"
  , "lib": "./lib"
  , "test": "./test"
  }
, "dependencies": {"hashish": "", "qs": ""}
, "devDependencies": {"vows": ">= 0.5.6"}
, "main": "./lib/embedly.js"
, "scripts": { "test": "vows" }
, "bin":
  { "embedly_oembed": "bin/embedly_oembed.js"
  , "embedly_objectify": "bin/embedly_objectify.js"
  , "embedly_preview": "bin/embedly_preview.js"
  }
}
```

Comment: The other common difference is the trailing common in any of the dictionaries or arrays.  The JSON must not have a trailing comma.

Comment: This threw me too as I had to wrap a boolean in quote marks. It was passing on http://jsonlint.com/ without the quotes.

Answer (score 16):

Just to complete the answer, you can simply use an online JSON validator to validate your `package.json`.
I highly recommend http://jsonlint.com/, paste your `package.json` in the textarea and click on the Validate button, that's all!

Comment: And I higly recommend my way of validating json objects @afshin Mehrabani

Answer (score 9):

Super cool way to fix / validate the package.json :

> `node package.json`

and you have your json validated or the error line.

Why use [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/), sounds pretty lame.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Hans Engel's answer use `npm help json` to get the specification of what should be in the package.json file

Answer (score 0):

I have been through this problem and in my case it was just that in place of comma(,).
I have used dot(.).
You can simply open it up in any JSON validator and it will help you up.
One of the JSON validator's link is as follows .
http://www.bodurov.com/JsonFormatter/

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error message, first run `npm package.json` to check errors in package.json file, if not then run `npm cache clean`.