# Receive parse error for package.json. Validates as valid json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, package.json

I'm trying to create my first yeoman generator and I'm  getting the following error when I run yo to create my project.

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.14
npm ERR! file /Users/derek/Development/personal_projects/stylus-generator/work/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token }
npm ERR! File: /Users/derek/Development/personal_projects/stylus-generator/work/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/derek/Development/personal_projects/stylus-generator/work/npm-debug.log
```

I've validated the package.json file using jsonlint. I've also performed npm cache clean. The package.json file can be found here: https://github.com/dereksnow/generator-simple-stylus/blob/master/package.json

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like he expects your JSON as string, not a javascript object literal.

Comment: @Tyr, it validates as JSON. I thought npm would handle if it is used in the context of a string. I'm not sure what else to look at if it's validating as JSON. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What needs to change in this package.json file to work with npm 0.3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644410/what-needs-to-change-in-this-package-json-file-to-work-with-npm-0-3-0)

Comment: @Barun I had looked at this answer before posting my question. I believe my question is different in the respect that I was noting that the package.json file itself was valid JSON. So this question/answer draws attention to potential problems in dependencies that other users may also miss due to the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a comma after my last dependency in my app/templates/_package.json file. I was looking at the package.json in the root directory which did not have any issues. Oof!