# How to install Grunt on Windows?

Tags: gruntjs

When I try to install Grunt via npm it fails with the following error stack.

```
E:\Client\Pune\Clodura\Development\Dev>grunt serve
'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

E:\Client\Pune\Clodura\Development\Dev>npm install -g grunt-cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Bitnami\\nodejs-0.10.35-0\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Bitnami\\
nodejs-0.10.35-0\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "gr
unt-cli"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.18
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Sanchi Solution\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\wrappy\1.0.2\pa
ckage\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Sanchi Solution\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\wrappy\1.0.2\p
ackage\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\Client\Pune\Clodura\Development\Dev\npm-debug.log
```

How do if fix this issue?

Comment: Show your package.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What needs to change in this package.json file to work with npm 0.3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644410/what-needs-to-change-in-this-package-json-file-to-work-with-npm-0-3-0)